# Changing x-axis to log scale rotates ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R data frame `d` which I'd like to display as a bar plot:

```
   size num_tasks  n
1    16         4  3
2    32         4  1
3    64         4 10
4   128         4 19
5   128         8  3
6   256         4 18
7   256         8  3
8   512         4 26
9   512         8 12
10  512        12  3
11 1024         4 18
12 1024         8 26
13 1024        12 11
14 1024        16  2
15 2048         4  2
16 2048         8 13
17 2048        12  2
18 2048        16  1
19 4096         4  3
20 4096         8 27
21 4096        12 30
22 4096        16 16
23 8192         8 16
24 8192        12 54
25 8192        16 81
```

The snippet I use to do this looks as follows:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=size, y=n, fill=num_tasks)) +
       geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

This works fine, but I would additionally like the x-axis to be logarithmic. But when I modify my snippet accordingly, i.e.:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=size, y=n, fill=num_tasks)) +
       geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
       scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')
```

I obtain the following plot in which the orientation of the bars is cleary incorrect:

[image]

To me this seems like a bug in ggplot2. What can I do to work around it?

Comment: I don't get your bottom plot when I copy your code, I get a plot with vertical stacked bars

Comment: @astrofunkswag Strange, what version of ggplot2 are you using? (mine is ggplot2_3.3.0)

Comment: thanks I do get the error w updated version, maybe that's related to the issue

Comment: I just downgraded to 3.2.0 and it works for me too. I will submit a bug report later.

Comment: btw log scale with bar charts is ill-advised. It can be difficult to read and leads to issues, `log(0)` is negative infinity so the bar chart has to start at 1

Comment: Since you're specifying an x and y aesthetic, I'd recommend going with `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`.