# Bar chart - bars jumped to y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, zero

I was plotting a bar chart with the code which worked perfectly well until some of the data had a value of 0.

```
barwidth = 0.35

df1:
norms_number   R2.c 
1             0.011     
2             0         
3             0.015         
4             0.011         
5             0         
6             0.012

df2:
norms_number  R2.c
1           0.001           
2           0           
3           0.012           
4           0.006           
5           0           
6           0.004

test <- ggplot()+
geom_bar(data=df1, aes(x=norms_number, y=R2.c),stat="identity", position="dodge", width = barwidth)+
  geom_bar(data=df2, aes(x=norms_number+barwidth+0.03, y=R2.c), 
stat="identity",  position="dodge",width = barwidth)
```

my result was:

[image]

and I got a warning that position stack requires non-overlapping x intervals (but they are not overlapping?)

I looked into it and changed the DV to factor (from numeric), which half helped, because now the graph looks like this:

[image]

why are the bars on the y axis? how else can I get around this weird error with values of 0?

Comment: What version of R and ggplot2 are you using.  There may be a bug with version 3.3.0.  This question might be related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597844/changing-x-axis-to-log-scale-rotates-ggplot-barplot

Comment: R version 3.6.3
R studio 1.2.5033
ggplot2 3.3.0
are you referring to ggplot version? how do I go to an earlier one?

Comment: If you flip adding the correction it seems to work: `ggplot()+
  geom_col(data=df1, aes(x= norms_number+barwidth , y=R2.c), width = barwidth, fill="blue") + 
  geom_col(data=df2, aes(x=(norms_number), y=R2.c), width = barwidth)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are intending to plot a bar chart where the heights are represented by a *value* rather than by *number of cases*.  [See here for more details](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html), but you should be using `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`.

With that being said, the error you are getting and the result is because it seems with `x=norms_number+barwidth+0.03` you are trying to specify the precise positioning of the second set of data (`df2`) relative to the first set of data (`df1`).

In order for `ggplot` to dodge, it has to understand what to use as a basis for the dodge, and then it will separate (or "dodge") each observation containing the same `x=` aesthetic based upon that particular group used as the basis.  Under normal circumstances, you would specify in `aes(` something like `fill=`, and `ggplot` is smart enough to know that whatever you set as `fill=` will also be the basis for `position='dodge'` to function.  in the abscence of that (or if you wanted to override that), you would need to specify a `group=` aesthetic that would be used for dodging.

Ultimately, this means that you need to combine your datasets and provide `ggplot` a way of deciding how to dodge.  This makes sense, since both of your dataframes are intended to be placed in the same plot, and both have identical `x` and `y` aesthetics.  If you leave them as separate dataframes, you can overplot them in the same plot, but there is no good way to have `ggplot` use `position='dodge'`, because it needs to see all the data in the `geom_col` call in order to know what to use as the basis for the dodge.

With all that being said, here's what I would recommend:

```
# combine datasets, but first make a marker called "origin"
# this will be used as a basis for the dodge and fill aesthetics
df1$origin <- 'df1'
df2$origin <- 'df2'
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# need to change norms_number to a factor to allow for discrete axis
df$norms_number <- as.factor(df$norms_number)
```

You then use only one call to `geom_col` to get your plot.  In the first case, I will use only the `group=` aesthetic to show you how `ggplot` uses this for the dodge mechanism:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=norms_number, y=R2.c)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge', width=0.35, aes(group=origin), color='black')
```

[image]

As mentioned, you can also just supply a `fill=` aesthetic, and `ggplot` will know to use that as the mechanism for dodging:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=norms_number, y=R2.c)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge', width=0.35, aes(fill=origin), color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: I might have to make it more complicated and use fill for stacked bars later on, but at least now I understand where the problem is, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if you are trying to draw something more complicated like a bar over a bar etc.. anyhow, one way is to use `geom_rect()` if you want to have one over the other:

```
ggplot()+
geom_rect(data=df1, 
aes(xmin=norms_number-barwidth,xmax=norms_number,
ymin=0,ymax=R2.c))+
geom_rect(data=df2, 
aes(xmin=norms_number,xmax=norms_number+barwidth,
ymin=0,ymax=R2.c))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:6)
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it didn't show here for some reason but ultimately I want two bars next to each other, and then potentially something on top of them, but for now I'm trying to figure out the simplest version. Will try this thank you.